# Running Time of the Fibonacci Matrix Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, runtime, time-complexity, big-o, fibonacci

I am trying to learn from Dasgupta , Papadimittriou and Vazirani - Algorithms. I found a question which I am not able to answer, any help/hints would be appreciated.

One of the ways to find Fibonacci series is by using:
    [Fn Fn+1]=[0 1 1 1]^n . [F0 F1]

The running time of this according to me, should be `O(n^2 * Log n)`. `"n^2"` for multiplication of n-bit numbers and "log n" for the number of times multiplication is needed.

However, the book suggests that the running time would be `O(M(n))` where `M(n)=theta(n^a), 1<=a<=2`. Could you tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the algorithm in more detail.

You are correct that then algorithm does O(log n) multiplications, but in order to analyze the runtime we need to see how big the numbers being multiplied actually are. The Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially quickly. In fact, they grow asymptotically as Θ(φ<sup>n</sup>). The number of bits in a number is proportional to the base-2 logarithm of that number, so the number of bits in the binary representation of the nth Fibonacci number will be roughly lg φ<sup>n</sup> = n lg φ = Θ(n).

We could do the analysis the way you have and say that since we're doing O(log n) multiplications and that each multiplication works with numbers that are at most n digits each and that each multiplication takes time O(n<sup>2</sup>) time that the runtime will be O(n<sup>2</sup> log n), but this isn't a tight bound.

To tighten things up, let's think about how to write a recurrence relation for the runtime of this algorithm. If we want to raise our matrix to the nth power, we recursively raise the matrix to the (n/2)th power, then square that result (possibly multiplying in one more copy of the original matrix if n is odd). Assuming the cost of multiplying two (n/2)-digit numbers is O(n<sup>2</sup>), this gives us the recurrence

> T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n<sup>2</sup>).

Using the Master Theorem, we see that this solves to O(n<sup>2</sup>) without the log term. The reason for this, intuitively, is that the last multiplication does dramatically more work than any of the previous multiplications, so much so in fact that summing up the work of all the preceding multiplies gives something asymptotically dominated by the last multiply. So that gets rid of the log factor.

The other insight here is that we can actually multiply n-digit numbers faster than O(n<sup>2</sup>). There are a number of algorithms developed over the years for doing this (famously, Karatsuba's algorithm, and more recently Furer's algorithm) that run in time O(n<sup>α</sup>) for some constant 1 ≤ α < 2. If we use one of those faster algorithms, the recurrence becomes

> T(n) = T(n/2) + O(n<sup>α</sup>)

and this solves, by the Master Theorem, to O(n<sup>α</sup>), matching your source.

To summarize:

1. We first confirmed that the numbers we were multiplying together had Θ(n) digits at step n.
2. We then wrote a recurrence relation for the runtime using a naive multiplication algorithm, which solved to a quadratic term without any log factors.
3. Finally, we improved that recurrence relation by using better multiplication algorithms to tighten our runtime bound.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible ways of computing Fibonacci numbers:

1) There is a closed form expression, which you derive by treating it as a linear recurrence, at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression

2) This appears to be diagonalizable matrix so you can write it as PDP^-1 where D is diagonal and (PDP^-1)^n=P D^n P^-1. Since D is diagonal, you can compute its powers by just taking the power of each diagonal element. In fact the fibonacci matrix is mentioned explicitly in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#An_application

Comment: I am not sure I understand. How is this related to the running time/time complexity of the algorithm?

Comment: These alternatives avoid exponentiation by repeated squaring of integers, replacing it with calls to functions such as pow() or exp() and ln() for doubles or floats. If doubles or floats are good enough for you this should save time. There is at least theoretical consideration to the cost of evaluating these functions in extended precisions, and I suspect that this would be theoretically competitive here, too, but I have no idea whether there are good libraries that support this in practice.